# How to search to find a video NOT in YouTube?

Tags: google-search

I want search some videos that are NOT listed in YouTube. I tried `-YouTube`, but it does not return any results.

How I can do that?

Comment: @harrymc why/ how that helps? Do other search engines not index YouTube?

Comment: I tried the following in google     """video site:-youtube.com"""  . Youtube is huge, but I don't believe that there is no other video that does not list in Youtube

Comment: Rather `-site:youtube.com`

Comment: `-keyword` allows you to omit any results in the search that contain `keyword`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-site:"youtube.com" intext:"hello"
```

then click the videos tab

just read this to make the above
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-Google-dorks-1

Answer (score -1):

Beside harrymc comment which is perfect you should be able to search for videos on a particular site using this query:

```
video that I am looking for site:the_site_on_which_you_look.com
```

Comment: Might be simpler to google for "video that I am looking for" and then click on the "Videos" tab. This will search more websites than just YouTube.